# Non Uniform Scaling vs Shear in Image Transformation

Tags: transformations, 2d-graphics

I am reading computer graphics. I am unable to distinguish between Non-uniform Scaling and Shear. Can someone explain the difference with two different examples?

Comment: There is in fact no difference. Consider a rectangle not aligned with the axis and apply a non-uniform scaling. What you get is a parallelogram... Conversely, any linear transformation can be seen as a combination of rotation and non-uniform scaling, by singular values decomposition of the matrix.